# c++: Simple TCP server not accepting data from client

Tags: c++, tcp

I have to create a simple tcp server that accepts some commands from the server and responds to them in a certain way. I started with just a simple thing in which server accepts anything from client as command and responds `"In response to your command"` to client 10 times as answer. But even this is not working. Please help.

server.cpp

```
# include <string.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <netdb.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <sys/socket.h>
# include <netinet/in.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

void *task1(void *);

static int connFd;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pId, portNo, listenFd;
    socklen_t len; //store size of the address
    bool loop = false;
    struct sockaddr_in svrAdd, clntAdd;

    pthread_t threadA[3];

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cerr << "Syntax : ./server <port>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    portNo = atoi(argv[1]);

    if((portNo > 65535) || (portNo < 2000))
    {
        cerr << "Please enter a port number between 2000 - 65535" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //create socket
    listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(listenFd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char*) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

    svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

    //bind socket
    if(bind(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot bind" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    listen(listenFd, 5);

    len = sizeof(clntAdd);

    int noThread = 0;

    while (noThread < 3)
    {
        cout << "Listening" << endl;

        //this is where client connects. svr will hang in this mode until client conn
        connFd = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntAdd, &len);

        if (connFd < 0)
        {
            cerr << "Cannot accept connection" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Connection successful" << endl;
        }

        pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, task1, NULL); 

        noThread++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < noThread; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threadA[i], NULL);
    }
    cout << "All threads have joined" << endl; 
}

void *task1 (void *dummyPt)
{
    cout << "Thread No: " << pthread_self() << endl;
    char test[300];
    char outbuf[300];
    bzero(outbuf, 301);
    bzero(test, 301);
    bool loop = false;
    int recvdBytes = 0;

    strcpy(outbuf, "Enter your username: \n");
    write(connFd, outbuf, strlen(outbuf));
    bzero(outbuf, 301);

    read(connFd, test, 300);
    string uname(test);

    strcpy(outbuf, "You are logged in\n");
    write(connFd, outbuf, strlen(outbuf));
    bzero(outbuf, 301);

    while(!loop)
    {    
        bzero(test, 301);

        read(connFd, test, 300);

        string tester (test);
        cout << tester << endl;

        if(tester == "exit")
            break;

        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            strcpy(outbuf, "In response to your command");
            write(connFd, outbuf, strlen(outbuf));
            bzero(outbuf, 301);  
        }
    }
    cout << "\nClosing thread and conn" << endl;
    close(connFd);
}
```

client.cpp

```
# include <string.h>
# include <cstring>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <netdb.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/socket.h>
# include <netinet/in.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <sstream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <strings.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string>
# include <time.h>
# include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sockFd, portNo;
    bool loop = false;
    struct sockaddr_in svrAdd;
    struct hostent *server;
    char inbuf[300];
    int recvdBytes=0;

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        cerr << "Syntax : ./client <host name> <port>"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    portNo = atoi(argv[2]);

    if((portNo > 65535) || (portNo < 2000))
    {
        cerr << "Please enter port number between 2000 - 65535"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }       

    //create client skt
    sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockFd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(server == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Host does not exist" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char *) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));
    svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *) server -> h_addr, (char *) &svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr, server -> h_length);

    svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

    int checker = connect(sockFd,(struct sockaddr *) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

    if (checker < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot connect!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    recvdBytes = read(sockFd, inbuf, 300); 
    cout << inbuf;
    bzero(inbuf, 300);

    cin >> inbuf;
    write(sockFd, inbuf, strlen(inbuf)); // sending my user name to server
    bzero(inbuf, 300);

    read(sockFd, inbuf, 300); // recieving the message from server
    cout << inbuf;
    bzero(inbuf, 300);


    // send commands to server
    for(;;)
    {

        char s[300];
        //cin.clear();
        //cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Enter command: ";
        bzero(s, 301);
        cin.getline(s, 300);

        write(sockFd, s, strlen(s));

        // recieve data in response to your command
        while(read(sockFd, inbuf, 300))
        {
            if(strcmp(inbuf, "done") == 0) // display the output
                break;
            cout << inbuf;
            bzero(inbuf, 300);      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "not working"? Does nothing happen, or does something unexpected happen, and in that case what *does* happen?

Comment: One thing that jumps out is `bzero(s, 301);` when `s` has 300 elements.

Comment: Nothing happens from server side. I keep on sending commands to the server but it doesn't respond.

Comment: I am not sending any data more than 300. Just simple words. Like abc, def...

Comment: To clarify: passing 301 to `bzero` is undefined for all your 300-element arrays. Fix that bug first.

Comment: can you connect e.g. with netcat?

Comment: I don't know netcat but I see I can connect to the server because it displays:
Listening
Connection successful
Listening
Thread No: 140149439805184

Comment: What happens if you don't start a thread but call `task1` directly?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have fixed that 300 element array bug, but the issue is not resolved.

Comment: @MartinBonner When I call task1 directly, then also this same thing happens. One more thing I observed just now that in threaded version of the original program, "Listening" is displayed twice on server side. This I mentioned in my previous comment also.

Comment: OK.  So you can get it to happen single thread.  Great!  Run your server under the debugger and single step through it until it doesn't behave as you expect.

Comment: No I don't get expected behavior in single thread even. Same thing happens as in multi thread program @MartinBonner.

Answer (score 1):

Usual problems.

- `connFD` should not be static. It should be a local variable in both `main()` and `task1()`, and it should be communicated to the started thread somehow. Otherwise the next client will clobber it and break the first client.
- You aren't error-testing `listen()`.
- You're ignoring the result of `read()` everywhere. You have to store it into a variable and check it for -1, zero, or a positive value: only in the positive case should the loop continue; and the positive value should be used to limit the number of bytes in the buffer you regard as having been received.
- You are ignoring the result of `write()` everywhere.

So at present there is no evidence that anything has been sent anywhere by anybody.

Comment: Well, you are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing out. I will implement this error checking code later. I just wanted to know why the server is not responding to the client even after connection is created. By the way, this same program works fine with telnet. Server responds when I connect using Telnet.